# self.title = @"My Title";

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

Can this be set more dynamically instead of hard coded?

```
self.title = @"My Title";
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I want the title to be the name of the row the user clicks on instead of Hard Coded Title name

In my viewController, I have State Names. I want the title to be the state name the user clicks on. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't that clear. In general you can set the title of the current view to be any  NSString object, so

```
self.title = string;
```

However what I'm guessing your asking is whether you can set the tile of a view which is created and brought into view when you click on a **UITableViewCell**. If so the answer is yes you can. You can do this in the **tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:** method of your view controller when you create the new view.

You need to pass either the **indexPath** variable or the text label from the cell **cell.textLabel.text** into a custom init method. So if you had a view controller called **nextController** for instance you'd do something like,

```
NextController *next = [[NextController alloc] initWithIndexPath: indexPath];
[appDelegate.navController pushViewController:next animated: YES];
[next release];
```

inside the **tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:** method of your main controller. Then in your **NextController** class you'd override the **init** method along the these lines,

```
-(id)initWithIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ( self == [super init] ) {
        indexVariable = indexPath;
    }
    return self;
}
```

after declaring the **indexVariable** in you **@interface**. The all you need to do is set the title of your new view form the **viewDidLoad:** method of your new controller, either grabbing the cell's label using the **NSIndexPath** or directly if you passed the label instead.

Answer (score 0):

Alasdair's answer is correct, but may be more complex than what you need.

In your **tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:** method, you probably have something that looks like (as in Alasdair's example):

```
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init]; //some flavor of "init"
[self.navController pushViewController:viewController animated: YES];
[viewController release];
```

All you really need to do is add:

```
[viewController setTitle:<<the string you want to set it to here>>];
```

after the first line above. Alternatively, you could pass the string in through a custom init, and set it from inside your pushed view controller. Either way.

But it's not really necessary to expose the entire table view to the underlying view controller.

Comment: Yup, that'd also work and is a lot simpler if setting the title is all you really need to do. I generally pass the NSIndexPath through so I can retrieve the original cell if I need it in the new view controller.